# Efficient replacement for ppval

Tags: performance, matlab, interpolation

I have a loop in which I use ppval to evaluate a set of values from a piecewise polynomial spline. The interpolation is easily the most time consuming part of the loop and I am looking for a way improve the function's efficiency.

More specifically, I'm using a finite difference scheme to calculate transient temperature distributions in friction welds. To do this I need to recalculate the material properties (as a function of temperature and position) at each time step. The rate limiting factor is the interpolation of these values. I could use an alternate finite difference scheme (less restrictive in the time domain) but would rather stick with what I have if at all possible.

I've included a MWE below:

```
x=0:.1:10;
y=sin(x);
pp=spline(x,y);
tic
for n=1:10000
    x_int=10*rand(1000,1);
    y_int=ppval(pp,x_int);
end
toc

plot(x,y,x_int,y_int,'*') % plot for sanity of data

Elapsed time is 1.265442 seconds.
```

**Edit** - I should probably mention that I would be more than happy with a simple linear interpolation between values but the interp1 function is slower than ppval

```
x=0:.1:10;
y=sin(x);
tic
for n=1:10000
    x_int=10*rand(1000,1);
    y_int=interp1(x,y,x_int,'linear');
end
toc

plot(x,y,x_int,y_int,'*') % plot for sanity of data

Elapsed time is 1.957256 seconds.
```

Comment: A piecewise polynomial spline is rather complex.  You're not going to do any better than ppval in evaluating one, but perhaps you could use a simpler representation.  Just a straight grid with linear interpolation, perhaps?

Comment: Hi Peter, I've edited my question in response to what you said. Linear interpolation would be more than acceptable but it just appears to be less efficient (unless there is a more efficient method than interp1).

Comment: Those times don't seem too bad to compute 10 million values. How fast do you want it to go?

Comment: My actual function currently computes approximately 10000 times as many values (closer to 100 billion calculations), which is taking around 3 hours to run. It's really not too bad but if there was a way I could reduce this by 50% then it would save me a fair bit of time!

Comment: from your code snippet it seems like the loop is parallelable, although you did say the values need to be calculated "at each time step". If you can use parfor, it will definitely be faster.

Comment: That snippet of code definitely benefits from parfor(~4x faster on my computer)! I'm not sure I can implement it on my actual function though!. I'll have a play and let you know.

Comment: Ah, nope, each loop actually relies on values from the previous step, which means that I can't use parfor!

Comment: There is a bug in your timing code: with `C = rand(1000,1)`, you are generating numbers between 0 and 1, while your interpolation grid is from 1 to 100, so what you are timing is extrapolation! This probably triggers some special condition in both `ppval` and `interp1`, so the obtained times are not realistic.

Comment: Apologies - I've changed the MWE, which should now be correct.

Comment: @BasSwinckels is right, but that only makes `ppval` faster. However, it's kind of a cheat to not include the very costly evaluation of `spline` in the timing, though `ppval` has the advantage of being able to use this intermediate data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slow, because you're running into the **single most annoying** limitation of JIT. It's the cause of many many many oh so many questions in the MATLAB tag here on SO:

***MATLAB's JIT accelerator cannot accelerate loops that call non-builtin functions.***

Both `ppval` and `interp1` are *not* built in (check with `type ppval` or `edit interp1`). Their implementation is not particularly slow, they just aren't fast when placed in a loop.

Now I have the impression it's getting better in more recent versions of MATLAB, but there are still quite massive differences between "inlined" and "non-inlined" loops. Why their JIT doesn't automate this task by simply recursing into non-builtins, I really have no idea.

Anyway, to fix this, you should copy-paste the essence of what happens in `ppval` into the loop body:

```
% Example data
x = 0:.1:10;
y = sin(x);
pp = spline(x,y);


% Your original version
tic
for n = 1:10000
    x_int = 10*rand(1000,1);
    y_int = ppval(pp, x_int);
end
toc


% "inlined" version

tic

br = pp.breaks.';
cf = pp.coefs;

for n = 1:10000

    x_int = 10*rand(1000,1);

    [~, inds] = histc(x_int, [-inf; br(2:end-1); +inf]); 

    x_shf = x_int - br(inds);    
    zero  = ones(size(x_shf));
    one   = x_shf;
    two   = one .* x_shf;
    three = two .* x_shf;

    y_int = sum( [three two one zero] .* cf(inds,:), 2);
end
toc
```

Profiler:

[image]

Results on my crappy machine:

```
Elapsed time is 2.764317 seconds.  % ppval
Elapsed time is 1.695324 seconds.  % "inlined" version
```

The difference is actually less than what I expected, but I think that's mostly due to the `sum()` -- for this `ppval` case, I usually only need to evaluate a *single* site per iteration, which you can do without `histc` (but with simple vectorized code) and  matrix/vector multiplication `x*y` (BLAS) instead of `sum(x.*y)` (fast, but not BLAS-fast).

Oh well, a ~60% reduction is not bad :)

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you more quickly! I've just implemented this in my actual code. 63% reduction in run time! Thanks for the thorough explanation too, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit surprising that `interp1` is slower than `ppval`, but having a quick look at its source code, it seems that it has to check for many special cases and has to loop over all the points since it it cannot be sure if the step-size is constant.

I didn't check the timing, but I guess you can speed up the linear interpolation by a lot if you can guarantee that steps in x of your table are constant, and that the values to be interpolated are stricktly within the given range, so that you do not have to do any checking. In that case, linear interpolation can be converted to a simple lookup problem like so:

```
%data to be interpolated, on grid with constant step
x = 0:0.5:10;
y = sin(x);

x_int = 0:0.1:9.9;

%make sure it is interpolation, not extrapolation
assert(all(x(1) <= x_int & x_int < x(end)));

% compute mapping, this can be precomputed for constant grid
slope = (length(x) - 1) / (x(end) - x(1));
offset = 1 - slope*x(1); 

%map x_int to interval 1..lenght(i)
xmapped = offset + slope * x_int;
ind = floor(xmapped);
frac = xmapped - ind;
%interpolate by taking weighted sum of neighbouring points
y_int = y(ind) .* (1 - frac) + y(ind+1) .* frac;

% make plot to check correctness
plot(x, y, 'o-', x_int, y_int, '.')
```

Comment: Given the look-up nature of the problem, the only way I can see that you will work faster than ppval is by taking advantage of the specific structure of your problem, as suggested by @Bas-Swinckels.

Comment: Very good! It gives me around a 50% reduction in running time, which is a huge bonus.